# Android to excel. jExecl making 0b files

Tags: java, android, excel

I am trying to make an excell file in Eclipse, using jExcel poi. Everything seems fine, no errors, it even makes the files but they are 0b large and cannot be opened.
I managed to get the file to an usb, from my tablet, where i run my code..when i open it on my PC it says :"The file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Veify that the file is not corupted and is from a trusted source before opening."
Then it asks me if l want to open it. When I say 'Yes', it opens a new BLANK excell file. Not the file i made in java.
here is my code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    try {
        WritableWorkbook wb = createWorkbook("Busotina "+n+".xls");
            WritableSheet sheet = createSheet(wb, "Prvi",0);
                    writeCell(0, 0, "poz", true, sheet);
        writeCell(2, 0, "poz", true, sheet);
        writeCell(1, 1, "poz", true, sheet);
        writeCell(2, 3, "poz", true, sheet);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
          }

public WritableWorkbook createWorkbook(String fileName) throws WriteException{
    WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
    wbSettings.setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(true);
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sd.getAbsolutePath() + "/JExcelTest");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File wbfile = new File (dir, fileName);
    WritableWorkbook wb = null;
      try {
        wb=Workbook.createWorkbook(wbfile, wbSettings);
        wb.write();
        wb.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            return wb;
}
public WritableSheet createSheet(WritableWorkbook wb, String sheetName, int sheetIndex){
    return wb.createSheet(sheetName,sheetIndex);
}
    public void writeCell(int columnPosition, int rowPosition,String contents, boolean 
                           headerCell, WritableSheet sheet) throws WriteException{
            Label newCell = new Label (columnPosition,rowPosition,contents);
            if(headerCell){
        WritableFont headerFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL,10,WritableFont.BOLD);
        WritableCellFormat headerFormat = new WritableCellFormat(headerFont);
        headerFormat.setAlignment(Alignment.CENTRE);
        newCell.setCellFormat(headerFormat);
            }
    sheet.addCell(newCell);
}
```

}

So, does anybody has an idea why it makes the directory, makes the file wanted but the file is 0.00B large and cannot me opened or puted in attachment of an Email or anything.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your files output streams are not closed properly (therefore the files appear to be 0 Bytes and can not be accessed by other programs.

Another thing that is strange is that you close the workbook before making your changes.
You should only do that after you inserted the content.

You should try to code your `createWorkbook` method like this:

```
public WritableWorkbook createWorkbook(String fileName) throws WriteException{
    WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
    wbSettings.setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(true);
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sd.getAbsolutePath() + "/JExcelTest");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File wbfile = new File (dir, fileName);
    WritableWorkbook wb = null;
      try {
        wb=Workbook.createWorkbook(wbfile, wbSettings);
        wb.write();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(wb != null) wb.close();
    }         
    return wb;
}
```

Comment: Ok, now it makes file size of a 13.5kb, but they still cannot be oppened. Same message again